# Android - Periodic Background Service

Tags: java, android

I want to create a Periodic Background Service a period with 2 mins. I want to start service when I approve a login to my application and kill the service when I logout or when I killed my application

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    public Context context = this;
    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Service is still running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        /* IF YOU WANT THIS SERVICE KILLED WITH THE APP THEN UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE */
        //handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you add this service to the manifest? How did you set this up, if not?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I add this servis in andorid manifest

Comment: 10000ms != 2 minutes

Comment: @Toorop yes I edit and put 1000 * 60 * 2

Comment: try adding some log statements because I'm not very confident that you can display a toast from a bg. service.

Comment: why periodic service? why don't you start a service and call its async method through your activity? service will automatically be close when app will be killed..

Comment: You should use Timer instead of Handler.. it will work well

Comment: @AndroidGeek so how can do this ? I create a service in servis next I did asyntask but I want to repeat this asyntask in perdiod time how i can do this ?

Comment: I have service code but little different , instead of running service every 2 minutes , it runs service when an activity is opened and check last time when service is runned , if it is more than 1 hr service will run again  , If you want me to post this code ?? i will post it ..

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka see my answer below

Comment: Just start the service and put up a notification that its running.  Using a runnable in a service is like asking to have the program crash sometime in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
int timerCount = 1;
private long period=120;

for (; timerCount <= period; timerCount++) {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (timerCount == period) {
           stopSelf();
      }
}
```

Use This code as timer for your code.

@Toorop is right. Try to print log instead of Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below function in your service, and put `Scheduletask()` in your service `onCreate()` Method

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    private void Scheduletask()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Scheduletask","Running .................");
                new RetrieveDataTask().execute();
                handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
            }
        });
    }

    private class RetrieveDataTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(InputStream... urls) {
            return "Task Executed";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d("Scheduletask",result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok but in this service I want to send a photo in asytask and I want to send all photos and repeat this asyntask in period

Comment: And how it will look this Scheduletask() ?

Comment: you cannot guarantee that your all pictures are uploaded within 2 mins or not. it depends on network connection. it better to not start repeated task, you can start another asynctask in onPostExecute() method to upload another picture

Comment: Ok I think I want to do just like this first I start an astntask and send 1 photo on onPostExecute() I will check if is another photo to send and execute one more time taks but when I check and is no photo to send I use a handler and wait 2 mins and check if is photo to send it is good idea ?

Comment: ok but I have one more question can I execute onPostExecute this same asytask ?

Comment: i couldnt understand your question . can you explain it a bit more